# TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Excuse me for the noob question.

I am using https://newsapi.org/ in my rails app and I am using httparty gem.

```
def news
    @techcrunch = HTTParty.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=766c2f65e93c477451455xxxxxxxxxxx',
    :headers =>{'Content-Type' => 'application/json'} )
    respond_to :html, :json 
end
```

news.html.erb

```
    <% if (@techcrunch.nil? or @techcrunch== []) %>
    <p> <h2>No news found.. Sorry</h2></p>
    <% else %>
      <% @techcrunch.each do |techcrunch| %>
          <td><%= link_to(image_tag(techcrunch["urlToImage"], height: '100', width: '100'), techcrunch.articles["url"])%></td>
          <td><%= link_to(techcrunch["title"], techcrunch["url"]) %></td>
          <td><%= techcrunch["publishedAt"] %></td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I am now getting an error

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

in the line

```
<td><%= link_to(image_tag(techcrunch["urlToImage"], height: '100', width: '100'), techcrunch.articles["url"])%></td>
```

I checked the API in postman and the response is as below

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "source": "techcrunch",
    "sortBy": "top",
    "articles": [
        {
            "author": "Matthew Panzarino",
            "title": "Apple Music’s first new personalized playlist wants you to Chill",
            "description": "This week Apple is beginning to roll out the first new personalized playlist under Apple Music’s ‘For You’ section. The playlist, entitled ‘Chill’..",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/27/apple-musics-first-new-personalized-playlist-wants-you-to-chill/",
            "urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/img_0021.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
            "publishedAt": "2017-06-28T02:45:58Z"
        },


        {
            "author": "Josh Constine",
            "title": "Facebook now has 2 billion monthly users… and responsibility",
            "description": "Thirteen years after launching and less than five years after hitting 1 billion, Facebook now has 2 billion monthly active users. If getting to 1 billion was..",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/27/facebook-2-billion-users/",
            "urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/facebook-users-snapchat-twitter-youtube-whatsapp-instagram-wechat-qq.png?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
            "publishedAt": "2017-06-27T17:06:05Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I display all the articles using news.html.erb?

Any help is Highly Appreciated.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
techcrunch.articles["url"]
```

`techcrunch["articles"]` is an array. You might want to iterate through articles:

```
<% @techcrunch["articles"].each do |techcrunch| %>
```

and remove `.articles`:

```
techcrunch["url"]
```

from where it failed.

Comment: ,Thank you for your quick response.I tried replacing techcrunch.articles[0]["url"].now I am getting error like 
"undefined method `articles' for ["status", "ok"]:Array"

Comment: Oh, sorry, please see an update: you should iterate over articles in the first place.

Comment: ,Thanks a ton. your solution has fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the api response on your console to see what you're getting and go from there.

```
def new
  ...etc
  puts @techcrunch
end
```

or even inside the view, before everything `<%= @techcrunch %>`
You're probably looping through a string and not an object, and the error comes from it being a string and when you call ["urlImage"] it should be an integer indicating an index and not a string ("urlImage"). You'll need to parse and organise the response first before iterating through it.

Also, you can just call:

```
if @techcrunch.blank?
```

instead of .nil? && == []

Comment: How does this answer the question stated?

Comment: It tells you how. "You'll need to parse and organise the response first before iterating through it.", explains the error and gives an advice for the syntax used. You can go ahead and complete it by querying the API, figuring out the response and writing it here, instead of wasting time commenting on a perfectly fine answer for a vague question.